# saving on a model with has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Here is my problem, I have three models:

ProductModel

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :title, :photo
  has_many :votes

  has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :medium => "300x300" }

  before_save { |product| product.title = title.titlecase }

  validates :title, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :photo, :attachment_presence => true

end
```

UserModel

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.from_omniauth(auth)
      where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
        user.provider = auth.provider
        user.uid = auth.uid
        user.name = auth.info.name
        user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
        user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
        user.save!
      end
    end
end
```

VoteModel

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  attr_accessible :user_id
end
```

Now I need to save on my VoteModel a record with the ProductId and the UserId. But I don't know how to do this, can anyone help me please?

UPDATE

---

here is my vote view

```
<%= form_for @vote, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :user_id %>
    <%= f.text_field :user_id %>

    <%= f.label :product_id %>
    <%= f.text_field :product_id %>

    <%= f.submit "Crear Producto" %>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Cancel', root_path %>
```

and here is the controller

```
class VotesController < ApplicationController

    def create
        @some_product = Product.find(params[:id])
        some_user = current_user
        vote = Vote.create(:user => some_user, :production => some_product)
        save!
    end

end
```

Comment: So you just want to create a Vote record belonging to a certain product and some user? Just use a standard form for that maybe with a hidden_field for the product, and then build the Vote based upon the current_user. I don't really get what your error or problem is.

Comment: Hi, well I was trying to do this on my rails console: user = User.first
product = Product.first
Vote.create(user, product)
and then a I get this error NoMethodError: undefined method `stringify_keys' for #<User:0x007ffba2361e38>

Comment: well it's expecting the id of the product and user. It needs to be Vote. create(user_id: some_user's_id, product_id: some_product's_id)

Answer (score 0):

First - your associations should be properly defined in all models:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :votes
  #...
  # bonus - to know who are the users who voted for the product
  has_many :users, :through => :votes
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :votes
  #...
  # bonus - to know what products a user has voted on
  has_many :products, :through => :votes
end

class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :user
  #...
end
```

Saving should be straight forward

```
Vote.create(:user => some_user, :production => some_product)
```

TO access votes from product

```
some_product.votes
```

To access users who votes from a product

```
some_product.users
```

Comment: thanks tamersalama, the Vote.create(:user => some_user, :production => some_product) goes in create action on my vote controller, right? also if you can help me with the view I really appreciate

Comment: I just published the controller and the view of the vote, because I'm getting this error: undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

Comment: Since it's a `form_for @vote` - the params[:id] will represent the id of the @vote. What you should use is `Product.find(params[:vote][:production_id])` . I understand that your form is just a temporary one (prototype) as I don't think you'd need to add both user and product ids in text fields. One more thing: You should treat Vote as any other model, ie: You could use Rails scaffold generator to build your basic Controller/Model/View on which your could expand.